# Database design for application with wiki-like functions

Tags: database, database-design

I'm making an api for movie/tv/actors etc. with web api 2 and sql server. The database now has >30 tables, most of them storing data users will be able to edit.

How should I store old version of entries?

Say someone edits description, runtime and tagline for a entry(movie) in the movies table.

I'll have a table(movies_old), where I store the editable files in 'movies' pluss who/when it was edited.

All in the same database. The '???_old' tables has no relationships.

I'm very new to database design. Is there something obviously wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my mind, there are two issues here: what table you store the data in, and what goes in the "historical value" field.

On the first question, there are two obvious options: Store old and new records in the same table, with some sort of indication of which is "current" and which is "history", or have a separate table for history.

The main advantage of one table is that you have a simpler schema. This is especially true if the table contains many fields. If there are two tables, then all the field definitions are duplicated. When you move data from the current table to the history table, you have to copy every field, and if the list of fields changes, or their formats change, you have to remember to update the copy. Any queries that show the history have to read two tables. Etc. But with one table, all that goes away. Converting a record from current to history just means changing the setting of the "is_current" flag or however you indicate it.

The main advantages of two tables are, (a) Access is probably somewhat faster, as you don't have so many irrelevant records to skip over. (b) When reading the current table you don't have to worry about excluding the history records.

Oh, an annoying thing about SQL: In principle you could put a date on each record, and then the record with the latest date is the current one. In practice this is a pain: you usually have to have an inner query to find the latest date, and then feed this back in to an outer query that re-reads the record with that date. (Some SQL engines have ways around this. Postgres, for example.) So in practice, you need an "is_current" flag, probably 1 for current and 0 for history or some such.

The other issue is what to put in the contents. If you're dealing with short fields, customer number and amount billed and so forth, then the simple and easy thing to do is just store the complete old contents in one record and the complete new contents in the new record. But if you're dealing with a long text block, like a plot synopsis or a review, there could be many small editorial changes. If every time someone fixes a grammar or spelling error, we have a whole new record with the entire 1000 characters, of which 5 characters are different, this could really clutter up the database. If that's the case you might want to investigate ways to store changes more efficiently. May or may not be an issue to you.

Comment: "(a) Access is probably somewhat faster, as you don't have so many irrelevant records to skip over"
Any idea how much? 5000 vs 100.000 entries, 2% faster? 30% faster?

Comment: If you don't have a usable index, then twice as many records will make any operation take twice as long. But the moral of that story is: have a usable index. Then performance is logarithmic: MULTIPLYING the number of records ADDS to the run time. The exact formula depends on a lot of factors, but you might find that, say, every time you double the number of records you add 1 millisecond to the query, that sort of thing. I don't know how big you expect your database to be. In practice, you usually have to have tens of millions of records before this becomes an issue.

Comment: Performance is more important than keeping the schema simple. I'm going with separate tables so that I can keep the entry's(movie, person etc.) id as index.

Thanks for answering!